# Managed package not letting me add a new custom field to already packaged object

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, custom-field

I have a new field on an object that has already been packaged in my package org. This field is referenced in Apex as well.

When I go to my package and look at the components, this field is not pulled in. So when I go to add it, it does not show up in custom fields to add to the package. The field is there!! I have done this before to managed objects (adding an additional field). I don't get what it isn't liking about this one.

I am not getting why the managed package will not recognize it or let me pull it in at all. It is just a simple number field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your field is referenced in Apex the managed package is automatically adding it for you to the package, no need to manually add it.

[Components Automatically Added](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=packaging_components_auto_added.htm&type=5)

No need to worry, you are good to go!

Comment: It doesn't show up at all in my items in my package. Before when I've dealt with new stuff it will show up on your package page automatically with no package number associated with it. This time it's not happening

Comment: Nope, just a regular release package. Maybe it just won't show up anymore until you actually package? Maybe they changed how that works? I don't really know

Comment: That is what it sounds like. I had the same issue 2 weeks back and by packaging it it appeared.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Different package Included By values]

Just for reference, the ***Included By*** for the custom fields that were automatically added only appeared upon packaging (and if I'm not wrong, during Beta dev it just doesn't appear)

Comment: Yeah I'm familiar with seeing something like that first field in your image for automatically added stuff on the managed package page you see before you hit 'upload'. But this field is nowhere to be seen

Comment: Let me know how it goes, I just know I saw the same behavior (was looking everywhere for the field to add it but never found it). Good thing is that the field made it in automatically and is now listed.

Comment: Yay it did just come through when I actually packaged. It had me worried...

Comment: Thanks for confirming!